# String overflow in C++? This inecessant beeping is weird

Tags: c++, string, buffer-overflow

I'm startin development on a junk file generator, but for some reason if I use a large number it will beep infinitely until the file is finished, I'm thinking there is a \a character somewhere in the ascii table, or it's overflowing and causes an error beep. Anyone wanna explain why this thing is screaming at me?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>
#define print cout<<

using namespace std;

int numberof,i;
char charvalue;
string charlist,filename;

int main()
{
    srand (time(NULL));
    print "What do you want the name of your file to be?(with a .txt extension)\n";
    getline(cin,filename);
    print "\nHow many characters do you want?\n";
    cin>>numberof;

    for(numberof>0;numberof!=0;numberof--)
        {
        i = rand() % 255 + 32;
        charvalue=i;
        charlist=charlist+charvalue;
        print charlist;
        }

    ofstream writefile(filename.c_str());
    writefile<<charlist;
    writefile.close();
    ShellExecute(NULL, "open", filename.c_str(), NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    return 0;
}
```

Seems like at this point the characters are coming out alright in the end, but it only writes 1/4 of them to the text file. Anyone know why?

Comment: "infinitely until the file is finished".  That word, "infinitely", I do not think it means what you think it means.

Comment: @abelenky: Look for the evil `#define`.

Comment: well, abelenky, look up top. #define print cout<<

Comment: @aschepler:  good catch.  The #define is evil. The code will compile, but that don't make it right.

Comment: `print charlist;` only works because of an #define.  Technically acceptable; stylistically horrible.

Comment: Anyone want to help me figure out now why only 1/4 of the characters it generates actually get written to file? I guess I can assume some just aren't supported by either notepad or the fonts themselves.

Comment: I'm more than half tempted to remove the C++ tag.

Comment: @ssen: See my answer, you should write `i = rand() % 95 + 32;`.

Comment: Hrm. FredOverflow, I'm getting even less written to the file now...

Comment: Please, *please*, **please**, remove that #define. It makes kittens++ cry. :'(

Answer (score 7):

> i = rand() % 255 + 32;

You probably want this to be something like:

i = rand() % (255-32) + 32;

You also *really* want to get rid of this:

```
#define print cout<<
```

As it stands, when (not if) whoever is grading your homework decides to kill you, he (she?) will almost certainly be found not guilty of murder on the grounds that it was self defense.

Comment: I think that print thing caused a seg fault in my own brain when I first saw it.

Comment: I come from python, and this isn't for homework. I dont see why I shouldn't :/

Comment: @ssen: Because you want C++ programmers to understand your code with ease. Would Pascal programmers to `#define begin {` and `#define end }`? Oh wait... :)

Comment: I actually didn't notice the define until you pointed it out. I'm probably spending too much time in python.

Comment: @ssen: If you want to use Python, use Python. If you're going to use C++, use C++. This is neither fish nor fowl (but is foul).

Comment: @ssen: Use #define that way if you want to, and you promise never to show that code to another C++ programmer.  Several SO users were confused by it.  Heck, I saw and understood it, and then a minute later was confused by it anyway.

Comment: @Moo-Juice: Which prompts the question: why do people always want to put nails into me, and why does everybody think theirs will be the "final" one? :-)

Answer (score 2):

> I'm thinking there is a \a character somewhere in the ascii table

Yes, it is in position 7, I believe.

Also, this:

> ```
> for(numberof>0;numberof!=0;numberof--)
> ```

should be this:

```
 for(; numberof > 0; numberof--)
```

The condition goes **in the middle**, and you do not need any initialization, hence the empty statement at the beginning of the for-loop.

Also, the printable ASCII characters only range from 32 to 126, so you should write:

```
i = rand() % 95 + 32;
```

Also, the following is *extremely* inefficient, as it generates a new string object every time:

```
charlist=charlist+charvalue
```

Do this instead:

```
charlist.push_back(charvalue);
```

Comment: So just put in an "if" that if you get \a, don't add it to the list.

Comment: Should I be scared that you know the ASCII code for \a with no docs required? :-P

Comment: @Brent: I guess it comes from my asm time, where you inevitably learn important characters by heart. `db "hello world!$", 0d, 0a` ;)

Answer (score 2):

You meant to say

```
i = rand() % 223 + 32;
```

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you're printing the entire charlist every time means as fast as you can means that as soon as you generate at least a couple `\a` characters in the output string (the odds of which aren't too bad), you will get nothing but incessant beeping.

Comment: But I've limited the random numbers to 32 and above, unless I did something wrong...did I?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `print charlist` so you're not printing the bell characters out.